# View is null for fragments on Tablet

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am trying the Fragment basics source code available [here](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/FragmentBasics.zip) from Android Developers site. I converted the code to Kotlin by just using **Code > Convert To Kotlin** feature and tried running it on a Nexus 10 API 23 emulator tablet.

I am getting an error in `ArticleFragment` in this line:

```
fun updateArticleView(position: Int) {
    //here, there is no view in activity for ID article, so it's null
    val article = activity.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.article) as TextView
    article.text = Ipsum.Articles[position]
    mCurrentPosition = position
}
```

Error is:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.TextView
  at com.example.fragmentbasics.ArticleFragment.updateArticleView(ArticleFragment.kt:45)
```

I tried debugging it and there is no View in the activity for null when it should be. What is it I am missing?

Comment: Could you post the entire fragment code? At least untill you call `updateArticleView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the view in fragment as:

```
val article = view!!.findViewById(R.id.article) as TextView
```

**view** is the inflated view in the fragment.